# RemoteApps missing on IIS sites

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

I accidentally deleted RDWeb on Sites under IIS, Screenshot attached. Any suggestions on how to bring it back?

[image]

Comment: Install the Remote Desktop Web Access Role Service (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc772214.aspx)

Comment: @Brian Thanks for the suggestion, that role is already present and I don't seem to be able to remove it.